# Injective homomorphism $\phi : H\times N\to G$ defined by $\phi (h, n) = hn$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

Show that $\phi : H\times N\to G$ defined by $\phi (h, n) = hn$ is a injective homomorphism. $H$ and $N$ are normal subgroups of $G$, and $H\cap N = \{e\}$.

I know that if $hn = e$, then $h=e=n$, and $hn=nh$, for $h\in H$ and $n\in N$. I know the definition of homomorphism but I'm having trouble showing in this case.

Comment: So you know  $hn=nh $. Now what is the problem? You can write  $h_1h_2n_1n_2$ as $h_1n_1h_2n_2$.

Comment: Can you elaborate it for me? Still don't get it.

Comment: See [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2333666/497335).

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show  $\phi $ is a homomorphism, we need to prove that  $\phi ((h_1,n_1)\cdot  (h_2,n_2))=\phi ((h_1,n_1))\phi ((h_2,n_2)). $

Note that $$\phi ((h_1,n_1)\cdot  (h_2,n_2))=\phi((h_1h_2,n_1n_2))=h_1h_2n_1n_2=(h_1n_1)(h_2n_2)\\=\phi ((h_1,n_1))\phi ((h_2,n_2)).$$

Comment: To show that ϕ is injective we need to show that ker ϕ = {e}.
So Ker ϕ = {h, n ∈ H×N | ϕ(h, n) = e}.
Let  ϕ(h, n) = hn = e, as we already know this only happens if h=e=n.
Therefore, Ker ϕ = {e}. Is this proof correct?

Comment: @Vityôk Yes, you are right.